# How to Thread lists elementwise with the If function?

Tags: evaluation, mapthread

Consider the lists:

```
list1={a,b,c};
list2={x,y,z};
```

I want to [`Thread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html) [`If`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/If.html) elementwise across the lists. I can achieve this with [`MapThread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html) but cannot with [`Thread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html)

```
In[1]:= MapThread[If[#1>#2,1,0]&,{list1,list2}]
Out[1]= {If[a>x,1,0],If[b>y,1,0],If[c>z,1,0]}
```

It fails when I try to do it with [`Thread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html)

```
In[2]:= Thread[If[#1>#2,1,0]&[list1,list2]]
Out[2]= If[{a,b,c}>{x,y,z},1,0]
```

### Academic Question

How can I perform the functionality with [`Thread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html) instead of [`MapThread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html) ?

Comment: Also (very similar to posted methods): `Thread[If[#,1,0]]&@Thread[Greater[##]]&[list1,list2]`

Comment: Here's a different approach: `Subtract[1, UnitStep[Subtract[list2, list1]]]`. Or you can use [`BoolEval`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/BoolEval/), which does this under the hood.

Comment: Another variant, using `Thread` as requested: `If[#1 > #2, 1, 0] &[list1, list2] //. f_?(MemberQ[_List]) :> Thread[f]`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thread doesn't hold its arguments unevaluated. In

```
Thread[If[#1 > #2, 1, 0] &[list1, list2]]
```

the "body", `If[#1 > #2, 1, 0] &[list1, list2]`, was evaluated immediately. That left a form with nothing for Thread to thread over.

Academic answer (one of probably many):

```
Thread[Inactive[If[#1 > #2, 1, 0] &][list1, list2]] // Activate
```

Answer (score 6):

`Inner` is more suitable for this task then `Thread`.

```
Inner[If[#1 > #2, 1, 0] &, list1, list2, List]
```

> `{If[a > x, 1, 0], If[b > y, 1, 0], If[c > z, 1, 0]}`

Comment: (+1) Nice, @cvgmt!

Comment: @E.Chan-López Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just another way using `MapApply`:

```
MapApply[Function[{x, y}, If[x > y, 1, 0]], Transpose[List[list1, list2]]]
(*{If[a > x, 1, 0], If[b > y, 1, 0], If[c > z, 1, 0]}*)
```

Another way using `Map`:

```
If[#[[1]] > #[[2]], 1, 0] & /@ Transpose[List[list1, list2]]
(*{If[a > x, 1, 0], If[b > y, 1, 0], If[c > z, 1, 0]}*)
```

Another way using `Outer`:

```
Diagonal[Outer[If[#1 > #2, 1, 0] &, list1, list2]]
(*{If[a > x, 1, 0], If[b > y, 1, 0], If[c > z, 1, 0]}*)
```

Using `Thread`:

```
If[#[[1]] > #[[2]], 1, 0] & /@ Thread[Greater[list1, list2]]
(*{If[a > x, 1, 0], If[b > y, 1, 0], If[c > z, 1, 0]}*)
```

Just using `Thread` in a simpler way:

```
Thread[If[Thread@Greater[list1, list2], 1, 0]]
(*{If[a > x, 1, 0], If[b > y, 1, 0], If[c > z, 1, 0]}*)
```

Comment: The question mentioned that they know how to answer the problem with MapThread but wanted to know how to achieve the same with Thread.

Comment: Sorry, I've corrected it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Using `Thread`:

```
list1 = {a, b, c};
list2 = {x, y, z};

Thread[If[Thread[#1 > #2], 1, 0] &[list1, list2]]

(*  {If[a > x, 1, 0], If[b > y, 1, 0], If[c > z, 1, 0]}  *)

SeedRandom[0];
Thread[If[Thread[#1 > #2], 1, 0] &[RandomReal[1, 10], 
  RandomReal[1, 10]]]

(*  {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1}  *)
```

The problem with the code

Thread[If[#1 > #2, 1, 0] &[list1, list2]]

is that, while "`Thread[f[args]]`
'threads' `f` over any lists that appear in `args`,"
there are no lists in the arguments of the code that `Thread` is applied to. The code that `Thread` receives is `If[{a, b, c} > {x, y, z}, 1, 0]`.

If the goal is to thread a function `f` over lists `f[list1, list2]`, the standard ways are to use `MapThread` or make the function `Listable`:

```
Function[Null, If[#1 > #2, 1, 0], Listable][list1, list2]

(*  {If[a > x, 1, 0], If[b > y, 1, 0], If[c > z, 1, 0]}  *)
```

Generic operator:

```
thread[f_] := Function[Null, f[##], Listable];

thread[If[#1 > #2, 1, 0] &][list1, list2]

(* {If[a > x, 1, 0], If[b > y, 1, 0], If[c > z, 1, 0]}  *)
```

Of course, `MapThread` already does this, with a slightly different syntax:

```
MapThread[If[#1 > #2, 1, 0] &]@{list1, list2}

(*  {If[a > x, 1, 0], If[b > y, 1, 0], If[c > z, 1, 0]}  *)
```

While `thread[f]` and `MapThread[f]@*List` produce equivalent outputs, they are not identical computations, since `Listable` and mapping are implemented in different ways.